# How do I achieve an horizontal date list with scrolling functionality in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datepicker, flutter-layout

How do I achieve an horizontal date list with scrolling functionality like the gif below in flutter?[image gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz5r4.gif)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ListView with scrollDirection as Horizontal as simple as that
ex:

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children:[
   //your ui logic here

  ]);
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for answering. What I don't exactly is how to get the right date to keep appearing while scrolling

Comment: You have to use DateTime class and code it acc to your need :) . You basically check current date with the number if it is same you change background color.

let me post working code for you give me some time

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I'm expecting.